# Flexible Open Source ERP System/Framework that works on top a Graph Database?

Tags: open-source, er-diagram, erp, processes

As the title suggests, I am looking for an open source, graph-based ERP system that is "as flexible/customizable as it gets".

Basically, I need to be able to implement my own data structure (ie. modelled as ER-Diagram) and business processes (i.e. BPMN).

Any advice welcome! :)

Comment: [OFBiz](https://ofbiz.apache.org/) works with Postgres and [AgensGraph](http://bitnine.net/agensgraph/)  is a Postgres fork that provides a graph database. I haven't tried it, but maybe OFBiz works with AgensGraph

Answer (score 1):

For your problem you can use the open ERP Odoo version 10 it is the best free ERP you can use, it is a complete version that gives you a lot of possibilities and you can modify what you want 
Here is the link to download it : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/page/download

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but [ProcessMaker](https://www.processmaker.com/) has a free open-source version of their workflow and BPM software which has many features in the free version. A feature comparison of their free and paid versions is located [here](https://www.processmaker.com/processmaker-bpm), also see the comparison chart [here](https://www.processmaker.com/feature-comparison). A comparison of several open source BPM packages (including ProcessMaker) is available [here](http://www.enterpriseappstoday.com/management-software/slideshows/8-open-source-bpm-software-options.html).